# How to export a Neo4j graph into a Turtle file

Tags: neo4j, turtle-rdf

I'm trying to export Neo4j graphs into Turtle format but can't find any resource.

There have been lots of discussions and some plugin tools for importing different kinds of files into Neo4j, but not much for exporting (except into csv or json). Can someone point me to somewhere? Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: Good question. I have an idea that I'll convert to an answer soon. However, please clarify how much data you would like to export. A couple of thousands vs a couple million nodes need different approaches.

Comment: The main problem is that transforming a property graph to RDF involves multiple decisions: 1. which namespaces should be used? 2. how to format URI/IRIs, i.e. how to identify RDF resources? 3. how to map composite properties (arrays) 4. how to map properties on relationships? And many others.

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick response.  Fortunately I only need to export graphs with from 10 to 100 nodes each time.  Since I am interested in "round-tripping" my graphs (because there are some things it makes sense to do in OWL/RDF and some things much better done in Neo4j), your other questions are also relevant.  I would like to understand what I will lose when I go from Neo4j to RDF/Turtle, and what I lose when I go from RDF back to Neo4j. Once I understand this clearly, I can plan to work with "trimmed-down" graphs that don't lose data when moved in either direction.

Comment: For a quick overview, you might be interested in Jesus Barrasa's presentation at GraphConnect London: [slides](https://www.slideshare.net/neo4j/graphconnect-europe-2017-debunking-some-rdf-vs-property-graph-alternative-facts-neo4j), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1Mn178sEYg).

Comment: This video is very informative. Thanks! Looks like the last command in the demo in this video is some tool or algorithm that deserialize the Json (or maybe the graph itself) into back triples. If that's the case, I wonder if there already exists a tool that does that, or would I need to write my own parser?

Comment: A quick search resulted in a W3C page - this should be good enough to get you started: https://www.w3.org/2016/01/json2rdf.html. Please report back on your experience, and I'll formulate a concise answer from this discussion.